# Why does `nmap` say that a host is down even though it responds to `ping`?

Tags: ping, nmap

`ping 10.0.3.12` gets responses (from a Windows laptop).
But `nmap` says "Nmap scan report for 10.0.1.12 [host down, received no-response]", though it finds other hosts that are up.

This is consistently repeatable.

Am I using this incorrectly, or what?

```
$ uname -a
Linux ray-desktop 5.15.0-67-generic #74~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Feb 22 14:52:34 UTC 2023 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ ping 10.0.3.12
PING 10.0.3.12 (10.0.3.12) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.0.3.12: icmp_seq=1 ttl=128 time=5.55 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.3.12: icmp_seq=2 ttl=128 time=5.66 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.3.12: icmp_seq=3 ttl=128 time=4.81 ms
...

$ nmap -sn -vv 10.0.0.1/22
Starting Nmap 7.80 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2023-04-25 21:11 EDT
Initiating Ping Scan at 21:11
Scanning 1024 hosts [2 ports/host]
Completed Ping Scan at 21:11, 15.81s elapsed (1024 total hosts)
Nmap scan report for 10.0.0.0 [host down, received no-response]
Nmap scan report for rogers (10.0.0.1)
Host is up, received syn-ack (0.00086s latency).
Nmap scan report for 10.0.0.2 [host down, received no-response]
Nmap scan report for 10.0.0.3 [host down, received no-response]
...
Nmap scan report for 10.0.1.9 [host down, received no-response]
Nmap scan report for tv-lg (10.0.1.10)
Host is up, received conn-refused (0.0066s latency).
Nmap scan report for 10.0.1.11 [host down, received no-response]
Nmap scan report for 10.0.1.12 [host down, received no-response]
Nmap scan report for 10.0.1.13 [host down, received no-response]
Nmap scan report for receiver (10.0.1.14)
Host is up, received syn-ack (0.0052s latency).
Nmap scan report for 10.0.1.15 [host down, received no-response]
...
Nmap scan report for 10.0.3.9 [host down, received no-response]
Nmap scan report for ray-desktop (10.0.3.10)
Host is up, received conn-refused (0.00097s latency).
Nmap scan report for 10.0.3.11 [host down, received no-response]
Nmap scan report for 10.0.3.12 [host down, received no-response]     <<<<< ???
Nmap scan report for 10.0.3.13 [host down, received no-response]
...
Nmap scan report for 10.0.3.255 [host down, received no-response]
Read data files from: /usr/bin/../share/nmap
Nmap done: 1024 IP addresses (4 hosts up) scanned in 15.84 seconds

$ ping 10.0.3.12
PING 10.0.3.12 (10.0.3.12) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.0.3.12: icmp_seq=1 ttl=128 time=8.25 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.3.12: icmp_seq=2 ttl=128 time=3.90 ms
...
```

Comment: Possibly this bug: https://github.com/nmap/nmap/issues/92#issuecomment-1344514959